# Space out multiple dynamically created usercontrols

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls

So what im trying to do is create multiple instances of my usercontrol
[image]

Though I'm stuck on finding a way for them to be next to eachother like have a 5 pixel space between the next one created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to have a function that dynamically calculates it. I haven't tested this, but it should work. You just call `doGetAppXPosition` which loops thru all instances of your control and takes the last one found as the next x-position.

```
Dim App As New AppTab()
With App
    ...
    .Location = New Point(doGetAppXPosition, 5)
    ...
End With
Me.Controls.Add(App)

Private Function doGetAppXPosition() as Integer

    Dim xpos as Integer = 5
    For Each oControl As Control In YourForm.Controls
            If TypeOf oControl Is AppTab Then
                xpos = oControl.Right + 5
            End If
    Next

    Return xpos
End Function
```